# Continuous countup timer for Android Game

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a 3-level math game. Our professor wants me to put a timer that starts at first level and stops only if the user already finished the 3rd level. I have this 3 activity class since I have 3 levels. I made it like this so that I will not be confused.

My problem is how can I make a timer continuously within each activity? I tried the examples found on the internet but I can able to run it on the first level.

Please help , because I don't have any idea how can I make this possible.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the time when the game starts and then just calculate the current gameplay time according to that.

First you need to create the `static` variable to store the time in, we need it to be `static`, so it can be shared between classes easily.

```
public static long time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then if you want to get the current passed time since the game started, you would do the following.

```
double time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time_start) / 1000d;
```

- The `time` variable is the passed time since the game started, and it is in **seconds**.

Then if you further want to reset the gameplay time at any point you would just call.

```
time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: the first code you gave is for first activity right? and I will just display timer_start and to continue this on the other activity I'll just used the second code. Am I right?

Comment: Well you can add the `time_start` in you main activity and then just use the `time_start` in all of your other classes. Then if you want the actual time passed you need to calculate the `double time`. Which you just place where ever you want the time to get calculated.

Comment: When I paste the first code in my main activity, I got this error:

Illegal modifier for parameter time_start; only final is permitted

Comment: @pingboo23 Where do you paste it inside the main activity?

Comment: inside the onCreate method.

Comment: Well don't do that you need to put the `time_start`, in the class itself and not inside a method. That kinda says itself when the variable is a `public static` variable.

Comment: I changed it. And I try to display the value of the time_start in my textView, but after I run it, i got errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35697/discussion-between-pingboo23-and-vallentin)

Answer (score 0):

When opening a new Activity, use `intent.putExtra(currentTime)` so that the next Activity knows where to continue the timer from.

Comment: I tried it. But I only got errors. I think, there's specific countup timer I should use in my first activity.